# How to do I Change a service installer's setup registry location

Tags: visual-studio, service, windows-services, windows-installer

I know that the conventional location for registry keys associated with a service are usually found in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/.  However, one of my co-workers is wondering if the this can be changed to a custom location, like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/RandomName.  Is this possible in a Visual Studio setup project? If not, is there another way to make it possible?

Also, would it affect how the service works?

Comment: This sort of begs the question why you need this? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The service supports an application that I am making for a company.  One of their lead IT members asked if I could put the registry keys for both application and service in one location, so that it can be a lot easier for them to report and target versions for deployments